# javascript objects: getting data from object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have problem with returning the value of object property

```
function Obj() {
this.objects =
        [
            {
                id: 0,
                values: {
                    x: 10,
                    y: 10
                }
            },
            {
                id: 1,
                values: {
                    x: 15,
                    y: 20
                }
            }
        ];
    }
Obj.prototype.getOjects = function() {
    return this.objects;
};
Obj.prototype.getModifiedOjects = function() {
    var i, obj;
    obj = this.getOjects();

    for(i=0; i<obj.length; i++ ){
        obj[i].values.x *= 2;
        obj[i].values.y *= 2;
    }
    return obj;
};

var obj = new Obj(), modifiedObjects;
console.log(obj.getOjects()); // value of 0 => {x => 10, y: 10}, 1 => {x => 15, y: 30}
modifiedObjects = obj.getModifiedOjects(); // Do something with mofified objects
console.log(obj.getOjects()); // value of 0 => {x => 20, y: 20}, 1 => {x => 30, y: 40}
```

When I call the **getModifiedOjects** function, also change the values of **objects** property.

How to make the **getOjects** function to not return object property by reference?

Thanks.

Comment: instead of returning the actual array. you could return a new object with just ids or the properties that you want to expose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in Javascript are passed around by reference (as you've discovered) so `getObjects()` just returns a pointer to the same object that is internal to `obj`.  The only way to make `getObjects()` return something completely different that can be modified without changing what `obj` has inside it is to make an explicit copy of the object.

Since your object has nested objects in it, you will have to make a "deep" copy so that everything is copied.

There are a variety of different ways to clone or copy your objects.  Here are some references:

[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

[What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object/122704)

Comment: Thank you so much for suggestion, i will try with cloning the object.

Answer (score 0):

To return a copy of the objects instead of the objects you need to create the copies:

```
Obj.prototype.getModifiedOjects = function() {
  var i, obj, result;
  obj = this.getOjects();
  result = [];
  for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    result.push({
      id: obj[i].id,
      values: {
        x: obj[i].values.x * 2,
        y: obj[i].values.y * 2
      }
    });
  }
  return result;
};
```